# Image is null when the file reaches the API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I select a file, I render this file in an `img` element without problem. But when I try to send it to the API, all other fields of my object are with values except for the image.

This is my class:

```
public class ImageDto2
{
    public IFormFile? Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string FileId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string IncidentId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

This is in the WASM

```
protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    _validationMessage = string.Empty;
    var validationResult = await Validator!.ValidateAsync(_imageDto!);
    var user = await LocalStorageService!.GetItem<string>("access_token");

    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(_imageFile!.OpenReadStream());
            content.Add(fileContent, "Image");

            content.Add(new StringContent(_imageDto!.Description), "Description");
            content.Add(new StringContent(_imageDto!.IncidentId), "IncidentId");
            content.Add(new StringContent("0"), "FileId");

            HttpClient!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            HttpClient!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", user);
            HttpClient!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            HttpClient!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
            var response= await HttpClient.PostAsync("/api/incidents/upload-image-web", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("success");
            } else
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("failed");
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        _validationMessage = validationResult.Errors?.FirstOrDefault()!.ToString();
}
```

This is the API:

```
[HttpPost("upload-image-web")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadImage([FromForm] ImageDto2 imageDto)
{
    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below:

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(_imageFile!.OpenReadStream());
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_imageFile!.ContentType);
                content.Add(fileContent, "Image","filename");
                .......
             }
```

it  works well on myside now:

[image]